# Why doesn't user_load return any values for a user's roles?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-theming

So I have this code in a template:

```
$thisuser = user_load(array('uid' => '11812'));
```

which, as far as I understand it, should return a user object for the user with the uid of 11812. And that object should contain an array of roles for that user in this variable:

```
$thisuser->roles
```

But that array doesn't exist.

I've traced through the user_load() function in modules/user/user.module with a debugger, and this code should populate the $user object with that roles array:

```
  $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {users} u WHERE '. implode(' AND ', $query), $params);

  if ($user = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $user = drupal_unpack($user);

    $user->roles = array();
    if ($user->uid) {
      $user->roles[DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID] = 'authenticated user';
    }
    else {
      $user->roles[DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID] = 'anonymous user';
    }
    $result = db_query('SELECT r.rid, r.name FROM {role} r INNER JOIN {users_roles} ur ON ur.rid = r.rid WHERE ur.uid = %d', $user->uid);
    while ($role = db_fetch_object($result)) {
      $user->roles[$role->rid] = $role->name;
    }
    user_module_invoke('load', $user_info, $user);
  }
  else {
    $user = FALSE;
  }
```

Everything's fine up through this line:

```
    $user = drupal_unpack($user);
```

but then, when we hit the next line, which should initialize an empty "roles" array in the $user object, nothing happens:

```
    $user->roles = array();
```

No "roles" array shows up in the object at all. The subsequent db queries work okay, and return the right role information, so this while loop:

```
    while ($role = db_fetch_object($result)) {
      $user->roles[$role->rid] = $role->name;
    }
```

has the proper values in $role->rid and $role->name each time through the loop, but $user->roles still doesn't exist, and the assignments here have no effect.

I'm beating my head against this - I can't figure out what's going on. I know that I can just query the db directly in order to get a user's roles if I really must, but why wouldn't the user_load() code work?

Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should just use user_load(11812), the former is deprecated and doesn't work at all in Drupal 7.

Comment: I tried it that way, too, but no dice. The problem goes away on a clean Drupal install, so it's got to be a module, I think.

Comment: Correction: problem persists on a clean Drupal install.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just did user_load(11812)? This has always worked for me up through Drupal 6.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work, either. I think I've figured out that it's being caused by a module - not sure which one. But when I do this on a couple other Drupal installs, it works as it's supposed to.

Comment: I would grep for _user( for a module invoking hook_user and possibly a bad load call. Though I have never experienced something removing values from a core load.

Comment: I will try that. But this gets weirder. It turns out it IS happening on all the Drupal installs I have. But user_load() is seems unable to insert more than 32 properties into the $user object. Once it gets to 32, further additions just don't take. I never noticed it before because I never had that much in $user->data before to unserialize via the drupal_unpack() function in user_load(). Now I do, and it fails beyond 32 items.

Comment: yep. just tried this on a bare drupal install. It seems the $user object can't have more than 32 properties. If the number of items in your $user->data property pushes the total number of properties above 32 after the data is unserialized, anything above 32 won't get added. Can't imagine what causes this.

Answer (score 0):

After much agony, I determined this ISN'T a problem in Drupal. It's my stupid debugger, MacGDBp. It has a bug (or an interaction with the macports version of the Xdebug plugin) that causes object instance variables not to be shown in the inspector when there are more than 32 variables.

So dumb.

Anyway, if you're using MacGDBp, beware of this issue.